# How to start and stop EC2 instance from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, automation

I have a requirement :
I have 3 ec2 instance A, B, C in A instance i jenkins already installed in that jenkins i need to create a pipeline job which will start and stop instance B & C.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to install the [Amazon EC2 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) and leverage it to start EC2 instances on demand, and correspondingly terminate them as they get unused.

Comment: Provide information on your anser not just a link

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Install aws cli:

```
sudo apt-get install awscli
```

Configure aws credentails for aws cli:

```
aws configure
```

Start ec2 instance:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids YOUR_INSTANCE_ID
```

Stop ec2 instance:

```
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids YOUR_INSTANCE_ID
```

Keep in mind that in order to start/stop an instance your instance has to have an Amazon EBS volume as its root device.

Reference:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html
2. http://shahzadlinux.blogspot.com/2019/04/how-to-stop-and-start-ec2-instance.html (Specific details for jenkins)

Comment: Please put the code example, the second link is no logger valid